# iPad Horizontal Swipe Cause Page to Jump Right or Left and Return

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

My site jumps momentarily right or left on swipe in iPad (prolitho.com).  I have overflow-x hidden and the viewport set:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" name="viewport"></meta>
```

Is there a way to lock it down so the whole site doesn't bounce right or left on a swipe?

Comment: Sure as soon as I post I figure it out.  My footer was too wide.  Set it to 100% and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a your fault, it's new iOS7 feature in Safari... at the moment no solution..

See this summary of safari changes in iOS7 that might cause problems to your website (including this swipe gesture)